# Limit user to post certain number of comments per article

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Somehow I'm running in circles for two days! I have MySQL Database and comments table in witch I have id, user_id, date, published_at, body, likes and dislikes. How to limit user for max 10 comments per day. Of course I have user table. 
I know I have somehow to count number of comments for certain date and put it in security context but I don't know how. I've tried with some native queries in 
Repository like:

```
@Query(value = "select count from comments WHERE published_at=?1 AND user_id=?2", nativeQuery = true)
public int brojPostovaPoDanuPoUseru(Date datum, Integer user_id);
```

I guess I should find logged user name from SecurityContext and after that find his id, but then again what if there are two users with a same name, and where to use SecurityContext to find this. 
At least some guidelines please :)

Comment: Ideally you shouldn't have two users with the same name , Can you provide an elaborate logic to uniquely identify a user in that case ? My suggestion is to have unique usernames and then from the controller check for the count of comments and throw a runtime exception if count exceeds.

Comment: Yes, you are right. My bad, User names may be the same but username for logging are supposed to be different! Now the question is how I check the num of comments for certain user?

Comment: How do you store your dates in the database ?

Comment: I'm using liqubase. Some of data are stored via csv, some through sql file via query. I have some apis I've made witch are functioning well and I can use them too to add some data to db (I guess standard way now with domain, repository, service and controller if you are asking that part).

Answer (score 0):

You can implement this on database level. My idea would be to save the time in seconds in `date` ( using Java: `System.currentTimeMillis()`). Then when you query by the user id, you can sort the results by `date` in descending order and filter for the top 10. Then you would pick the smallest number in `date` and check if it was less then 24h ago, if so you could then return an exception.

This would be an example query:

```
select * from (SELECT * FROM `comments` where comments.user_id=?1 ORDER BY `comments`.`date` DESC limit 10) as c order by c.date ASC limit 1
```

Let's say you saved `date` in secods using `System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000`. Now with the query result you would first calculate the seconds in hours and then in a day. This results in `86400` seconds. Now you would calculate the current time in seconds and extract it with the 24h in seconds as calculated before. And then you would check if this calculated result is smaller than the value of `date` this would indicate that the last 10th comment was made within the 24 hours.

This is the sample code in your repository:

```
@Query("select * from (SELECT * FROM `comments` where comments.user_id=?1 ORDER BY `comments`.`date` DESC limit 10) as c order by c.date ASC limit 1", nativeQuery=true)
public Comments  getLastTenthComment(int userId);
```

This is the sample code in your service:

```
public boolean isAllowedToComment(int userId){
   Comment comment = repository.getLastTenthComment(userId);
   int dayInSeconds = 86400;
   long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
   long yesterdayInSeconds = currentTime - dayInSeconds;
   if(comment.getDate() >= yesterdayInSeconds){
      return false;
   }
   return true;
}
```

Comment: I just had to add in if statement: comment.getDate().getTime() / 1000 and it worked like a charm. Many thanks to you, I'm new on stack and still cannot vote up publicly but you've got upvote from me. Also, just for info and maybe for some other people who wants to use this I've implemented this in controller through security @PreAuthorize("@authComponent.numberOfCommentsExceeded(#id)") and made a path through @PathVariable(value = "id")Integer id